# c libcurl POST doesn't work consistently

Tags: c, xml, post, curl, libcurl

I am trying to POST xml data from a c program using libcurl to a website.  When I use the command line program in linux, curl like this it works fine:

curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: text/xml' -d 'my xml data' http://test.com/test.php

(I changed the actual data for security)

But as soon as I try to write c code using libcurl, it fails almost every time but succeeds every once in a while.  Here is my c code:

```
CURL *curl;
CURLcode res;

curl = curl_easy_init();

if(curl)
{
    curl_easy_init(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://test.com/test.php");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, xmlString.c_str());
    curl_easy_perform(curl);
}

curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
```

I have this code in a loop that runs about every 10 seconds and it will only succeed about every 4 or 5 calls.  I get back errors from the server that say "XML Head not found".

I tried specifying the HTTP header with:

```
struct curl_slist *chunk = NULL
chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, "Content-type: text/xml");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, chunk);
```

But I didn't have any luck.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init(); 
if(curl) 
{ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://test.com/test.php"); 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, xmlString.c_str()); 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE, xmlString.length()); 
    struct curl_slist *slist = curl_slist_append(NULL, "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8"); // or whatever charset your XML is really using...
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, slist); 
    curl_easy_perform(curl); 
    curl_slist_free_all(slist);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl); 
}
```